# Winform control change event fire

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

There`s a winform I have developed, it has few radio buttons, Checkboxes, Dropdowns, and a textbox. Need to fill the textbox based on the selections made in the mentioned controls,

Ex: If am selecting radiobtn1, checkBox1 & dropdown1`s first value, then it should be like below

```
txtBox.text =  radiobtn1.Text_checkBox1.Text_dropdown1.SelectedIndex
```

Browsed on this and I found it that it could be done using delegates, but I have like 12 controls, do you suggest using delegates?
Any other short way to write this code?

Comment: This isn't a "Do my homework" forum.

Answer (score 0):

Prbably the simplest way to write the code is to create an event handler that fills the textbox.  It would look something like this:

```
private void UpdateTextbox(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //find the text
    txtBox.Text = string.Format("{0}_{1}_{2}", radiobtn1.Text, checkBox1.Text, dropdown1.SelectedIndex);
}
```

Then you just have to link all the events raised by changing your other controls to your event handler.

```
//Add these lines to the constructor of your control
radiobtn1.CheckChanged += UpdateTextbox;
checkbox1.CheckChanged += UpdateTextbox;
//and so on
```

Comment: Cannot use the code to replace when radiobtn2 or the rest are changed.

Comment: Yes you can.  I just showed a simple `UpdateTextbox` function, but you could have it determine which radio button is checked and then use the text from that radio button.